# Python IF statement to see how long an input has been active

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi, a pi face and a python script to monitor several home sensors. I want to add the sensing wire from the smoke detectors to that list but I need a bit of help with the if statement.

I'm unsure how to tell the if statement to check how long the input has detected the signal. Under 4 seconds disregard (low battery chirp), over 4 seconds (smoke detected) alert me..

Basically I need help writing the if statement below.

```
if piface.digital_read(0)==0 >= 4 seconds:
    # do x 
else:
    # do y
```

Do I need a loop and can it be as easy as what I have above? (Coded correctly of course!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested pseudo-code):

```
counter = 0
while True: #your main loop
    smoke = digital_read() #assume 0 = no alarm, 1 = alarm
    if smoke:
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 0
    if counter >= 4: #there was smoke for the last 4 seconds
        call_the_fire_brigade()
    time.sleep(1) #wait one second
```

I guess you probably need some loop.

Comment: I am actually using something similar to this but for a different function.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well I think a good solution to this would be spawn a separate thread for each detector and then use a blocking for the number with a loop.. like

```
count = 0
while count < 4:
    if piface.digital_read(0) == 0:
        count += 1
    else: count = 0
    sleep(4000)
# ... rest of code ...
```